# Getting a strange scatterplot like image when trying to create a violin plot using R ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, violin-plot

I am trying to create a violin plot comparing genetic variant class against age at time of surgery and I am getting some very weird results.

I have been using the below guide, which makes creating violin plots look easy:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization

```
plot = ggplot(df,aes(x=factor(Category), y=age.at.time.of.surgery)) + 
              geom_violin()
```

[image: Age at surgery for individuals with or without pathogenic variants]

Comment: your y variable is probably a factor or a character variable. Try transforming it to numeric or integer. `df$age.at.time.of.surgery <- as.numeric(as.character(df$age.at.time.of.surgery))`

Comment: Yep this works perfectly! Thank you